# How is this a half plane and not a half grid?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Gilbert Strang's 4th edition, page 7, problem 1.1B we have two vectors:

$v = (1,0)$ and $w = (0,1)$.

We look for the linear combinations $cv+dw$ with restrictions.

1. $c$ is a whole number
2. $c \ge 0$

He claims that adding all vectors $cv$ and $dw$ result in a half plane. I see no way to get anything other than a half grid with vertical lines through each of the whole $x$ values. I'm afraid that I missed something about combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood the solution by mixing up parts (1) and (2) of the exercises.  They are *separate*.  In the book's solution,

1. $c$ is a whole number (i.e $c \in \Bbb{N} \cup \{0\}$).  By varying $c$, you get

   - $cv = (c,0)$ are *equally spaced points* in (1)
   - $cv + dw = (c,d)$ are *parallel vertical lines*
2. $c\ge0$.  By varying $c$, you get

   - $cv = (c,0)$ is a *half line* (right half of the $x$-axis)
   - $cv + dw = (c,d)$ is a *half plane* (right half of the $xy$-plane)

Comment: That makes me feel better. I assumed (1.) and (2.) referred to a list of conjunctive conditions not two separate problems.  But I do that.